# this._getLayer is undefined leaflet group layer

Tags: javascript, plugins, leaflet

I want to integrate in my leaflet map this plugin https://github.com/davicustodio/Leaflet.StyledLayerControl.
I create the marker from a json:

```
jQuery().ready(function (){ 
$.getJSON(
    'recinto_new/json/json_track.php?days=' + days,
    function(data){
        var latlngs = Array();
        var coordinate = Array();
        var coordinate1 = Array();
        var cow = new L.LayerGroup();           
        for ( var i=0; i < data.length; ++i )
        {               
            if (i==0){
                var myIconStart = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'recinto_new/maps/images/start-cow.png',
                iconRetinaUrl: 'recinto_new/maps/images/start-cow.png',
                iconSize: [69, 70],
                iconAnchor: [9, 21],
                popupAnchor: [0, -14]
                });
                markerArray[i] = L.marker( [data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude], {icon: myIconStart, title: data[i].title } )
                .bindPopup( '<div>' + 'Alla data: ' + data[i].date + '<br/>'
                    + data[i].title + ' si trova'
                    + '<b>Latitudine: </b> ' + data[i].latitude + ' - ' + '<b>Longitudine:</b> ' + data[i].longitude + '</br>'
                    + '<b>Nome: </b>' + data[i].title
                    + '</div>',
                    {direction: 'left'} )
                .addTo( map );

            } else if(i == data.length-1){
                var myIconEnd = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'recinto_new/maps/images/end-cow.png',
                iconRetinaUrl: 'recinto_new/maps/images/end-cow.png',
                iconSize: [69, 70],
                iconAnchor: [9, 21],
                popupAnchor: [0, -14]
                });
                markerArray[i] = L.marker( [data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude], {icon: myIconEnd, title: data[i].title } )
                .bindPopup( '<div>' + 'Il bovino <b>' + data[i].title + '</b> si trova qui: ' + '<br/>'
                    + '<b>Latitudine: </b> ' + data[i].latitude + ' - ' + '<b>Longitudine:</b> ' + data[i].longitude + '</br>'
                    + '<b>Ultima rilevazione: </b>' + data[i].date
                    + '</div>',
                    {direction: 'left'} )
                .addTo( map );
                markerArray[i].openPopup();
                zoomTo(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude);

            } else {
                var myIcon = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'recinto_new/maps/images/cow.png',
                iconRetinaUrl: 'recinto_new/maps/images/cow.png',
                iconSize: [69, 70],
                iconAnchor: [9, 21],
                popupAnchor: [0, -14]
                });
                markerArray[i] = L.marker( [data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude], {icon: myIcon, title: data[i].title } )

                .bindPopup( '<div>' + 'Il bovino si trova qui: ' + '<br/>'
                    + '<b>Latitudine: </b> ' + data[i].latitude + ' - ' + '<b>Longitudine:</b> ' + data[i].longitude + '</br>'
                    + '<b>Nome: </b>' + data[i].title
                    + '</div>',
                    {direction: 'left'} )

                .addTo( map );


                    }
```

I create a layerGroup var cow = new L.LayerGroup(); and add a marker markerArray[i].addTo(cow);
Then I create a control and add to map: 
    var control = L.Control.styledLayerControl(baseMaps, overlays, options);
            map.addControl(control);
I visualize the menu but when I click on the checkbox for hide my marker the console give me this error: TypeError: this._getLayer(...) is undefined
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should add the code that creates your overlays as well. Make sure you share enough for people to be able to reproduce your issue. Ideally provide a live code snippet / Plunker / JSFiddle, etc.

Comment: Yes but I have a local library, how do I create a JSFiddle project?

Comment: You just build your code in the online editor, until your issue appears. You can link external resources. You can also use Plunker instead, which looks more like building a full HTML page, where you link external resources through common `<script>` and `<link>` tags.

Comment: Thank's for help, I've have seen that the plugin is not compatible with my version of leaflet. I have solved with another plugin (http://maydemirx.github.io/leaflet-tag-filter-button/)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Please consider writing your own answer and mark it as accepted, so that people with a similar issue as yours can later solve it quicker. Make sure to specify your lib versions.